# ScyllaHide DLL Injection

Tags: malware, windows, injection, debugging, library

When I try to perform a DLL injection with ScyllaHide in x32/x64 dbg, then it crashes for some reason, is this a bug? Both with stealthy injection as with normal injection, the program crashes when I inject a DLL.

For example, when I inject my own DLL or a standard Microsoft DLL in notepad.exe, the process crashes. I actually want to inject my DLL in malware, so that I can resolve its imports at runtime, but then it also crashes. No matter which binary I choose, also when I run as administrator.. it crashes when I try to inject a DLL..

Settings (note that when I inject the DLL with my own written injector in C, then it does inject the DLL in notepad.exe, but with ScyllaHide it doesn't work).

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons for ScyllaHide failing to inject DLLs include anti debugging measures, UAC and syntax errors in ScyllaHide.

Comment: Yes it looks like a bug in ScyllaHide, especially because notepad.exe does not have antidebug measures. When I inject a conventional DLL it works, but with Scylla it doesn't.